# Disable tag background color

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I double click a word in a html tag (editing an aspx file), I get a double background highlighting.

[image: screenshot of a line with double background color]

I have selected the word decSearchStartTime, but I also get the tag keyword button selected as well as attributes.

How do I only have the selected word highlit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the Tools menu and select "Options" Then under "Environment" -> "Fonts and Colors" it's under "Brace Matching (Rectangle)" in the Display Items list for the Text Editor. Technically you can't turn it "off" but you can have the Item Background color set to the same as your editor's background color which does effectively the same thing.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I was setting "Brace matcing (rectangle)" to "Automatic" and now I only have the starting `<` and `>` highlit. Tried to also change Brace Matching to black background color, but no change.

Comment: @AndersLindén There must be a difference between 2015 and 2017 - I've only got 2015 on this machine will dig my laptop out later (which has 2017) and see if I can replicate the behavior you are seeing.